# Giving context to tcp handler object

Tags: c++, oop, networking, tcp

I'm programming on a little tcp server application to practice and I have come accross a problem:

I have a tcp_server object which takes an tcp_abstract_handler object as argument.
Now i can just derive from tcp_abstract_handler and handle the incoming events.
The problem is that my_handler is isolated from the rest.
I created a small "context" struct to "connect" the handler to the objects that it needs. But this seems to be rather ugly. Are there patterns or common ways to solve this?

```
 struct my_server_context_t
 {
    unsigned int& num_connections; //just as example
 };

 class my_handler : public tcp_abstract_handler
 {
    public:
      my_handler(const my_server_context_t& ctx) 
        : ctx(ctx)
      {
      } 

      ... 


      void socket_connected_event(const socket_event_args& args)
      {
        ctx.num_connections++; 
      }

      void socket_disconnected_event(const socket_event_args& args)
      {
       ctx.num_connections--;
      }

    private:
      my_server_context_t ctx;
 };

 class my_server
 {
 public: 
   void run()
   {
     my_server_context_t ctx = { num_connections };
     tcp_server srv(listen_port, new my_handler(ctx));
     srv.run();
   }

 private:
   unsigned int num_connections;
 };
```

Comment: "`my_handler` is isolated from the rest". The rest of what? Why does the handler need to know how many other clients are connected? Usually independent connections need not know anything about one another, and just talk directly to the server. That would remove the need for the thin `my_server` wrapper around the `tcp_server` class.

Comment: I think that my question was a little bit imprecise. Basically I am just trying to find the "best" way to give every connection access to "global"/single instance - resources. This could be an object for configuration parameters which have been loaded at startup once for example.

Comment: There are a few common ways to do this, in that case. The simplest is just a global variable like you've got, which is fine. Another is the "singleton" pattern, but there are tradeoffs with that (SO has many good posts on singletons in C++). Another would be to give each handler a reference to the parent server, and store the necessary information in member data/methods there. Keep in mind that if there are multiple threads, you'll need to do some kind of synchronization to protect data integrity.